# What's going on with this bitwise operation?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Consider the two following sequences of bits

```
xxxx x100 0000 0000

xxxx x000 0000 0000
```

Why is `((int) sequenceOfBits >> 10) & 0x1;` not recognizing the difference?

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem?

Comment: This is not returning the correct value of the bit.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Example: This is what I expect, but this is wht I get instead.  thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? I'm running `System.out.println(1024 >> 10 & 0x1); System.out.println(2048 >> 10 & 0x1);` And they print `1` and `0` respectively

Comment: I'm always getting 0 when I expect to identify when the bit is 1. Is there any other workaround that I can use?

Comment: What is `sequenceOfBits`? Could you show us a piece of the actual code?

Comment: Why are you casting sequenceOfBits?  What is its data type?

Comment: I saw the int case - might `sequenceOfBits` (heaven forbid) be a `byte`?

Comment: It's too bad, because I am sure that your question is not hard to answer.  But your question is unnecessarily hard to understand. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If you do that, you'll get good answers within minutes or even seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any code, so I hope you're not doing this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte sequenceOfBits = (byte)1000000000L;
    System.out.println(((int)sequenceOfBits >> 10) & 1);
}
```

This will produce the result of 0

Byte sequence 10000000000 equals decimal value 1024.  So you really should have something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int sequenceOfBits = 1024;
    System.out.println((sequenceOfBits >> 10) & 1);
}
```

Do not confuse numerals in code to be binary even if they are just 0's and 1's

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(10000000000L));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((byte)10000000000L & 0xFF));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1024));
}
```

Output:

```
1001010100000010111110010000000000
0
10000000000
```